# How to fix player in sound menu

Tags: 16.04, indicator-sound, clementine

I have a fresh install of 16.04.LTS and Clementine.

Whenever I play a track on Clementine, the sound menu shows the song being played but doesn't show the 'stop' icon. Instead it shows the 'play' icon as if the song was on pause.

[image]

As a result I am unable to stop the song that is currently being played, and the previous/next button don't seem to work either.

I've seen answers here on how to remove this from the sound menu, but couldn't find any on how to fix this issue.

(I am not sure if it is an OS or app issue.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Clementine do you have? How did you install it? Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.1 (64bit). I installed the .deb from their site, and this happens in any new fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.